# Codeigniter give class not found error when i use MY_Controller

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter, class, codeigniter-3

**Issue**
When i try to call `http://my_url/api/login/gethomescreen` it is giving me error `Fatal error: Class 'MY_API_Controller' not found`
When i add following line top of `Login.php` `require APPPATH . '/core/MY_API_Controller.php';` then it is working fine.
Also it is working when i add `__autoload()` in config.php and load CI_Controller

But as per codeigniter structure, it should work without include file. Parent class should automatically load when i extend it. I just want to know why this is happening?
Here is my code and path details.
**Login.php**

```
class Login extends MY_API_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function gethomescreen_post(){
        //my code goes here
    }
}
```

**MY_API_Controller.php**

```
ob_clean();
require APPPATH . '/libraries/REST_Controller.php';
class MY_API_Controller extends REST_Controller {

    protected $_options = array();

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        // Load the jwt.php configuration file
        if (empty($options)) {
            $this->load->config('jwt', true);
            $options = $this->config->item('jwt');
        }
        $this->_options = $options;
        $this->load->model('users_model');
    }
}
```

**REST_Controller.php**

```
abstract class REST_Controller extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct($config = 'rest') {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->preflight_checks();
        //further code....
        }
}
```

**Files path**

`application\controllers\api\Login.php`
`application\libraries\REST_Controller.php`
`application\core\MY_API_Controller.php`

Comment: Rest Controller isn't a core Class - more under https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/core_classes.html

Comment: Yes, got it. But when i call Login api then it why it is not load? Or to load it need CI_Controller ?

Comment: Put MY_API_Controller.php in `application/controllers/` or in `application/libraries/`. CI will not look for it in `core` or any subfolders (without using and autoloader).

Answer (score 0):

In your config.php file in the config folder, is this line set:

```
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
```

to:

```
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_API_';
```